# Listactivity With Multiple button and multiple videos

Tags: android, android-intent

i have a listactivity app , consist of 5 rows , each row cotain one TEXT and 5 BUTTON , 
both text and buttons are clickable , text will open MyDay activity whic is textview and when you click any button it must open videoview screen , its work fine as image below :

[image]

**But my issue is  :**

i can assign five different videos to be opend by the 5 buttons in each row .

what im trying to have different video for each button so :

**25 button open 25 different videos** .

which i mean:

button **(one)** in **first** row will open **video_1**

button **(two)** in **first** row will open **video_2**

button **(three)** in **first** row will open **video_3**

button **(four)** in **first** row will open **video_4**

button **(five)** in **first** row will open **video_5**

button **(one)** in **second** row will open **video_6**

button **(two)** in **second** row will open **video_7**

and so on till last button in fifth row

i cant achieve that  .

any advice will be appreciated

THANKS

**MY  CODE :**

**ListButtons Class :**

```
 public class ListButtons extends ListActivity {
String classes[] = {"First",  "Second", "Third","Fourth", "Fifth" }; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter(this, classes));  }}
```

**MyArrayAdapter Class :**

```
 public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final String[] mClasses;
private Context mContext;
private Typeface tf;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private String[] mData = { "button1", "button2", "button3", "button4",
        "button5" };
private int[] ids = { R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3,
        R.id.button4, R.id.button5 };
int[][] rowDrawables = { 
        {R.drawable.row_1, R.drawable.row_2, R.drawable.row_3, 
             R.drawable.row_4, R.drawable.row_5},
        {R.drawable.row_6, R.drawable.row_7, R.drawable.row_8, 
             R.drawable.row_9, R.drawable.row_10},
        {R.drawable.row_11, R.drawable.row_12, R.drawable.row_13, 
             R.drawable.row_14, R.drawable.row_15},
        {R.drawable.row_16, R.drawable.row_17, R.drawable.row_18, 
             R.drawable.row_19, R.drawable.row_20},
        {R.drawable.row_21, R.drawable.row_22, R.drawable.row_23, 
             R.drawable.row_24, R.drawable.row_25}};

public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] classes) {
    super(context, 0, classes);
    mClasses = classes;
    mContext = context;
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "BFantezy.ttf");
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                              }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null, true);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.row_label);
        holder.textView.setTypeface(tf);
        holder.bt1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        holder.bt2 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        holder.bt3 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        holder.bt4 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
        holder.bt5 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button5);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    String s = mClasses[position];
    holder.textView.setText(s);

    int[] rowDr = rowDrawables[position];
    holder.bt1.setBackgroundResource(rowDr[0]);
    holder.bt2.setBackgroundResource(rowDr[1]);
    holder.bt3.setBackgroundResource(rowDr[2]);
    holder.bt4.setBackgroundResource(rowDr[3]);
    holder.bt5.setBackgroundResource(rowDr[4]);

    holder.textView.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
    holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Integer pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
            Intent ourIntent = new Intent(mContext, MyDay.class);
            ourIntent.putExtra("cheese", mClasses[pos]);
            mContext.startActivity(ourIntent);
                       }
                       });
    holder.bt1.setOnClickListener(mListener);
    holder.bt2.setOnClickListener(mListener);
    holder.bt3.setOnClickListener(mListener);
    holder.bt4.setOnClickListener(mListener);
    holder.bt5.setOnClickListener(mListener);
    return convertView;
                   }

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
    Button bt1, bt2, bt3, bt4, bt5;

                     }

private OnClickListener mListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String night = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            if (v.getId() == ids[i]) {
                night = mData[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, My_videos.class);
        i.putExtra("video", night);
        mContext.startActivity(i);
                                   }
                                   };

                                }
```

**My_videos Class :**

```
  public class My_videos extends Activity {  
private VideoView vid;  
String night;  
/** Called when the activity is first created. */  
@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    setContentView(R.layout.video); 

    Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    night = bdl.getString("video");   
    vid = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1); 

    if (night.equalsIgnoreCase("button1")) {    
    vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                + "/" + R.raw.video_1));
        vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));  
        vid.requestFocus();    
        vid.start(); }  

         else if (night.equalsIgnoreCase("button2")) {   
     vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                + "/" + R.raw.video_2)); 
         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
             vid.requestFocus(); 
             vid.start(); } 

         else if (night.equalsIgnoreCase("button3")) { 
     vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                + "/" + R.raw.video_3)); 
         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
             vid.requestFocus();
             vid.start();         } 
         else if (night.equalsIgnoreCase("button4")) { 
     vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                  + "/" + R.raw.video_4)); 
         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this)); 
             vid.requestFocus();     
             vid.start(); }         
         else if (night.equalsIgnoreCase("button5")) {   
     vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()  
                  + "/" + R.raw.video_5)); 
         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));   
             vid.requestFocus();      
             vid.start(); }  

                        }}
```

**UPDATE:**

I try to modify the  My_videos Class As below code but it end with **shows same video for every button** which is ( video_5 ) .

```
  public class My_videos extends Activity {  
private VideoView vid;  
String night;
private int position;  
/** Called when the activity is first created. */  
@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    setContentView(R.layout.video); 

    Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    night = bdl.getString("video");   
    vid = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1); 


 if(position == 0){ 
        night.equalsIgnoreCase("button1"); { 
     vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                     + "/" + R.raw.video_1));
        vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
        vid.requestFocus();
        vid.start(); }      
          if(position == 0){ 
       night.equalsIgnoreCase("button2"); { 
     vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                   + "/" + R.raw.video_2));
        vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
        vid.requestFocus();
        vid.start(); }  }            
          if(position == 0){ 
        night.equalsIgnoreCase("button3"); { 
       vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                       + "/" + R.raw.video_3));
         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); } }                
     if(position == 0){ 
      night.equalsIgnoreCase("button4"); { 
         vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                     + "/" + R.raw.video_4));
         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); } }                    
      if(position == 0){ 
        night.equalsIgnoreCase("button5"); { 
     vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                    + "/" + R.raw.video_5));
         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); }}

else if(position == 1){ 
       night.equalsIgnoreCase("button1"); { 
     vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()  
                   + "/" + R.raw.video_6));
         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); } }   
    if(position == 1){ 
         night.equalsIgnoreCase("button2"); { 
     vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                     + "/" + R.raw.video_7));
         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); } }            
    if(position == 1){ 
        night.equalsIgnoreCase("button3"); { 
         vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                       + "/" + R.raw.video_8));
              vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); } }                
    if(position == 1){ 
       night.equalsIgnoreCase("button4"); { 
         vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                     + "/" + R.raw.video_9));
         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); } }                    
    if(position == 1){ 
        night.equalsIgnoreCase("button5"); { 
     vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                   + "/" + R.raw.video_10));
         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); }}


 else if(position == 2){ 
        night.equalsIgnoreCase("button1"); { 
     vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                       + "/" + R.raw.video_11));
         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); }     }
    if(position == 2){ 
          night.equalsIgnoreCase("button2"); { 
     vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                 + "/" + R.raw.video_12));
         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); } }            
    if(position == 2){ 
        night.equalsIgnoreCase("button3"); { 
         vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                      + "/" + R.raw.video_13));
         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); }     }            
    if(position == 2){ 
         night.equalsIgnoreCase("button4"); { 
         vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                     + "/" + R.raw.video_14));
         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); } }                    
     if(position == 2){ 
      night.equalsIgnoreCase("button5"); { 
     vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                     + "/" + R.raw.video_15));
         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); }}

else if(position == 3){ 
      night.equalsIgnoreCase("button1"); { 
     vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                    + "/" + R.raw.video_16));
         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); } }   
      if(position == 3){ 
         night.equalsIgnoreCase("button2"); { 
     vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                      + "/" + R.raw.video_17));

               vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); } }            
      if(position == 3){ 
      night.equalsIgnoreCase("button3"); { 
         vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                 + "/" + R.raw.video_18));

             vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); } }                
      if(position == 3){ 
      night.equalsIgnoreCase("button4"); { 
         vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                         + "/" + R.raw.video_19));  

         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); } }                
      if(position == 3){ 
      night.equalsIgnoreCase("button5"); { 
     vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                       + "/" + R.raw.video_20));    

         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); }}             

 else if(position == 4){ 

    night.equalsIgnoreCase("button1"); { 
     vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                 + "/" + R.raw.video_21));
     vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
     vid.requestFocus();
     vid.start(); } }   
    if(position == 4){  

        night.equalsIgnoreCase("button2"); { 

    vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" 
               + R.raw.video_22));


                   vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
             vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); } }            
  if(position == 4){    

             night.equalsIgnoreCase("button3"); { 
         vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                    + "/" + R.raw.video_23));
                vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
          vid.requestFocus();
          vid.start(); }    }                
 if(position ==4){  
       night.equalsIgnoreCase("button4"); { 

        vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                  + "/" + R.raw.video_24));

         vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); } }

  if(position == 4){    
      night.equalsIgnoreCase("button5"); { 
     vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() 
                + "/" + R.raw.video_25));   

           vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));
         vid.requestFocus();
         vid.start(); }}
              }}
```

Comment: whats the reason for using a list view? Surely if its fixed to 5 rows its a little unnessesary?

Comment: @ jiduvah this is primay app in big project consist of 25 rows each text in row will open complex layout and each row will have not less than 15 videos so it must be listview

Comment: @Archie.bpgc this is primay app in big project consist of 25 rows each text in row will open complex layout and each row will have not less than 15 videos so it must be listview

Comment: Your problem is you are getting the same video for one-button in all the rows??

Comment: @Archie.bpgc absolutely right button (one) in all rows open same video and button (two) in all rows open same video but sure different than video opend by button (one) , and so on

Comment: In the previous question, I've posted a link. There you have a My_videos class that does exactly what you want. How did you miss it?

Comment: @Luksprog im not miss that and appreciate your help but check this question and its image , your link do this : when press any button it open videoview with 5 button in side the videoview it self and when press any button it open the video but in this question i want the buttons in the list it self when press it display the video directly in videoview (from the list it self we will have 25 button open 25 different videos ) , this is the difference ,if you have any idea please tell me , thanks

Comment: Check the link again https://gist.github.com/3463215 . I've modified the `My_videos` class + there are some changes to the `MyArrayAdapter` class. It should do what you want.

Comment: @Luksprog i apply the new change it gave me : open same video in each row but diffrenet video from row 1 to row 2 and so on , so in (first row :button 1 , button 2, button 3,button 4, button 5 ,open same video)and (second row :button 1 , button 2, button 3,button 4, button 5 ,open same video) ,and so on till last row , i want each button open different video , to have finally 25 button open 25 different videos . 
any advice please,thanks

Comment: I've made a simple mistake but you should have seen it. Check the link again and the `onCreate` method of `My_videos`.

Comment: @Luksprog you are really expert , its work finally , million thanks, please post it as answer so i will accepted my dear sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this link https://gist.github.com/3463215 I've posted a version of `My_videos` class that will do what you want. Basically, in the `MyArrayAdapter` class when a `Button` is clicked you will send in the `Intent` the row where that Button was clicked + the exact `Button` that was clicked in that row. Then in the `My_videos` class you'll get this numbers and easily find the correct video in an array of arrays data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 buttons, 25 links, 5 rows, And if u set 5 listener(for each button 1) u can select the uri like this ex:

```
button1,button2,button3,button4,button5;

button1.setOnclickListener(new View.onClickListener{
    public void onClick(View v){
        Integer pos = (Integer) v.getTag();
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(mContext, MyDay.class);
        ourIntent.putExtra("cheese", mClasses[rowPosition*5+buttonPostion]);
        mContext.startActivity(ourIntent);
    }
});
```

rowPosition=in `getView(position)` is simple curent convertView number, button position is your your `v.getTag()` button number now is 1.

Sow whit this u can select 25 link : exemple when u get onclick in your 2 row, 3rd button the link id will be 2*5+3=13 . so in your secund row the 3 buttom will get the 13 link to play.

Answer (score 0):

You get same video for all the ones, same video for all the twos so on, because you have the same ID for all the ones in all the rows and so on.

So, do this in the onClick:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        String night = null;
        int position = yourListView.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent())
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            if (v.getId() == ids[i]) {
                night = mData[i];
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

now add this position also as an Extra to your intent. So that you will know which row's one is clicked and so on.

Comment: do you mean replace this code : public void onClick(View v) { String night = null; for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) { if (v.getId() == ids[i]) { night = mData[i]; break; } }    with your code

Comment: yeah. when you are setting the adapter to your ListView. also give that  ListView as a parameter to the MyArrayAdapter. Now using this ListView you can get the Row of which button one is clicked, using the code above. Using this Row Position and the Text night, you show your respective video

Comment: is that will lead to when press each button will open different video for the 25 button which mean i will have 25 button assigned for 25 different video

Comment: look. you have 5 rows and each row has 5 buttons. so a total of 25 different button(but you cannot differentiate them only using there IDs, because you only have 5 IDs assigned 1 each to the Buttons in a specific row). So to differentiate all 25 buttons use the index of the row that button belongs to. So you can have something like this "if position = 0 and night = button1" means button1 of 1st row is clicked, so play 1st video. "if position = 4 and night = button5" means button5 of 5th row is clicked, so play 25th video.

Comment: yes yes this what i want also i try this code but does not work , im not expert in android : if(position == 0){
    night.equalsIgnoreCase("button1"); {    
   vid.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_1));
   vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(My_videos.this));  
   vid.requestFocus();    
   vid.start(); }

Comment: i don't have much idea about playing videos. If you know how to use Videos, the rest is simple logic. Better you check if you are getting the right values for "Position" and "night" when you click on any button using Logs

Comment: it not give error but all 25 button opend same one video only

Comment: if you dont mind, can you remove all the previous code from the question and post the new code(complete code) which shows same video for every button

Comment: do you mean to add that line you mention (position) to my intent

Comment: yeah add that position to the intent

Comment: then in My_videos take both night and position values and play video according to it.

Comment: but before all that, change the adapter constructor. Add listView parameter to the adapter. and change this line of code "setListAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter(this, classes, getListView()));"

Comment: i did all that  but in intent when add position line get red error line under (yourListView) also i changed to ListView but same red line error

Comment: MY LIST WHICH CONTAIN BUTTONS NOT INTIATED BY listview in xml layout , look for ListButton CLASS which intiate the list